# Bitwise or in match?

Tags: rust, bitwise-operators

I have a variable that consists of several flags ORed together, and I'd like to test which combination of them my value is and act on that. Unfortunately, the `|` operator has a different meaning in a `match` statement, so I can't write

```
match x {
    (FLAG1 | FLAG2) => return 5;
    (FLAG1 | FLAG3) => return 6;
    (FLAG2 | FLAG3) => return y;
    _ => return 0;
}
```

and instead I need to precompute `(FLAG1 | FLAG2)` and so on, making my code ugly and unreadable. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is a flags ORed ? Please include a [mcve] your question is unclear, what is `FLAG1` for exemple ?

Comment: My guess that you should use [bitflags](https://docs.rs/bitflags/1.0.4/bitflags/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The left part of each arm of a `match` expression is a *pattern* not an *expression*. That means you can only do pattern matching there. You can't use operators, accessors and function calls.

Unfortunately, I think you might be stuck with doing an `if..else`:

```
if x == FLAG1 | FLAG2 { return 5 }
else if x == FLAG1 | FLAG2 { return 6 }
else if x == FLAG1 | FLAG2 { return y }
else { return 0 };
```

But, since `if..else` (and `match`) are expressions, you can at least eliminate the repeated `return`:

```
return if x == FLAG1 | FLAG2 { 5 }
else if x == FLAG1 | FLAG2 { 6 }
else if x == FLAG1 | FLAG2 { y }
else { 0 };
```

Comment: You could do a `match` with guards. `match x { x if x == FLAG1 | FLAG2 => 5,` etc.

Comment: @trentcl You could. I'm not convinced that it's nicer though. Perhaps a matter of preference, but I find it weird when it's the same x being matched in every arm.

Comment: It is a little weird, but it lines up nicer than `if ... else if ... else` and is more compact after rustfmt :)

Comment: Note: since `if` is an expression, you don't actually need the `return` and `;` in the last case.

Comment: "The left part of each arm of a match expression is a pattern not an expression" yes, but if FLAG1 FLAG2 FLAG3 are const, wouldn't it be a constant evaluation? Or is the compiler still just not used to this syntax?

Answer (score 7):

You could work around this limitation by using an array of possible options:

```
const FLAG1: usize = 1;
const FLAG2: usize = 2;
const FLAG3: usize = 3;

fn main() {
    let x = 1;
    let y = 10;

    let options = [
        (FLAG1 | FLAG2, 5), 
        (FLAG1 | FLAG3, 6), 
        (FLAG2 | FLAG3, y)
    ];

    let result = options.iter()
                        .find(|(calc, _)| *calc == x)
                        .map(|(_, ret)| *ret)
                        .unwrap_or(0);
}
```

Depending on the number of variants you want to cover this might be a viable solution.

Comment: I like this answer because you separate the data from the process of selecting it. Of course, this won't work as well if you have a complicated expression as the value that needs computed.

Comment: That `if let` is awkward. Why not use `unwrap_or`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. thanks, totally forgot about that one :).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little macro to transform your code into a `match` with `if` guards. I named it `switch!` since it works a little more like `switch` from other languages.

https://github.com/camsteffen/switch-statement-rust

```rust
switch! { x;
    FLAG1 | FLAG2 => return 5,
    FLAG1 | FLAG3 => return 6,
    FLAG2 | FLAG3 => return y,
    _ => return 0,
}
```